# How to acces text of macros in an ms-excel worksheet from external code?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am working on cataloguing macros in the excel sheet. Is there any way to open an excel worksheet programatically and read source code of macros to look for a specific word?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Take a look here - 
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Something like this will do part of the work:

```
Sub ListProcedures()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Dim NumLines As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = WS.Range("A1")
    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
            Rng.Value = ProcName
            Rng(1, 2).Value = ProcKindString(ProcKind)
            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
            Set Rng = Rng(2, 1)
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```